# residualPlots - Why does it make no difference whether I use type = "response" or type "pearson"?

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals, heteroscedasticity

If I use type = "response", the Y-axis should actually show: real value minus estimated value.

In my case, for example, the following values would be plotted on the Y-axis: 1 (real value) - 1.2 (estimated value) = 0.2 or 2 (real value) - 1.2 (estimated value) = 0.8.

With Pearson residuals, the residuals would have to be divided by a value, which would produce other values. However, with type = "response" and type = "pearson" the graphs look exactly the same.

It is not clear to me by which value exactly the residuals are divided. The description says: "pearson residuals are weighted residuals, scaled by the square root of the weights used in fitting." Here it is said that they are divided by the estimated standard deviation of Y https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-020-01055-2#Tab1 ). I am a little confused.

In a linear regression, how is the normal Pearson residual calculated and how is the standardised Pearson residual calculated? What are the properties of the normal PR (mean and SD) and what are the properties of the standardised PR (mean and SD)?

Comment: In a standard linear regression, all observations have a weight of $1$.  That should pretty much answer all your questions.

Comment: Similar if not identical questions would arise across any software that supports different flavours of residuals like this, but it is still a good idea to spell out which software you are using.

Comment: In generalized linear models, there's many different residual definitions (at least six I think, before we even start worrying about the distinction between internal or external standardization). In linear regression, some of these distinct definitions coincide; you need to look with care into exactly what your software is computing for them (if the documentation/help doesn't make it explicit or at least give references, and you don't have source code, there's always trying to reproduce it yourself based on other resources).

Comment: @jbowman. Ah okay, yes this makes sense! Of course, if I calculate the pearson residuals with a weight of 1. It stays the same output as if I do real value - estimated value. The term "weight" confuses me a bit since in Uni we only have used this term for weights of predictors. How is the term to be understood in this context? @ Nick Cox. I use R Studio. Thanks for your feedback! @ Glen_b. Yes, it is sometimes very confusing to figure out how the residuals are calculated. The help page of the package primarily only said what I wrote above. Now it has become a little clearer to me. Thx a lot!